# find the eigen function and eigen value of differential operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, bessel-functions, eigenfunctions

I have an operator, defined in the cylindrical coordinate system with cylindrical symmetry, given by:
$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}+ \frac{\partial}{r\partial r} $

I would like to find the eigenfunction and their eigenvalues for this operator. I found that it will be Bessel function of the first kind. But I would like to know the derivation.